# MySql Condition Clause resulting in every joined line from joined table based on column value

Tags: mysql, left-join

The following are the related lines of my query that I have a problem I cannot resolve:

```
IF (servicesalesdetailsopen_v.complaintcode LIKE 'IVWIP', 'Y', 'N') as intflag

LEFT JOIN servicesalesdetailsopen_v

ON servicesalesopen_v.ronumber = servicesalesdetailsopen_v.ronumber and servicesalesopen_v.vehid = servicesalesdetailsopen_v.vehid and servicesalesdetailsopen_v.cora_acct_code = 'XXX-S'
```

The query brings back accurate results but line by line for detailed line items within the servicesalesdetailsopen table.  I only want a Y set as intflag if IVWIP is on ANY row in the servicesalesopen_v.complaintcode for the repair orders and it brings back every line item with a Y or an N for each line.  I would like the result in one line by RO.

How do I accomplish one line results by RO?

This is ongoing.  I don't want to have to address it when it's imported into another database.

Comment: Then you need to use some kind of a subquery to get aggregated result for each line. Since we have no clue about your data structure and your actual data, we can't tell you exactly how that would look like.